# Using Parse::CSV to limit splits

Tags: perl, parsing, csv

I am trying to use [Parse::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CSV) to parse through a simple CSV file with a header and 2 columns. The second column may contain commas but I want to ignore them. Is there anyway to limit how many times it splits on commas? Here is what I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Parse::CSV;

my $csv = Parse::CSV->new(file => 'file.csv');

while (my $row = $csv->fetch) {
    print $row->[0] . "\t" . $row->[1] . "\n";
}
```

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

> 1234,text1,text2
>
> 5678,text3
>
> 90,text4,text5

This would return

```
1234    text1,text2
5678    text3
90      text4,text5
```

Comment: You might want to try a different module like Text::xSV.  However given that your data indicates that you don't really have a CSV file, probably nothing will work.  In order to have a proper CSV file, there should be quotation marks around the fields that contain the comma.  Fix your datasource and Parse::CSV will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really wed to `Parse::CSV`, you can do this using a [filter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CSV#Writing-Filters):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Parse::CSV;

my $parser = Parse::CSV->new(
    file   => 'input.csv',
    filter => sub { return [ shift @$_, join(',', @$_) ] }
);

while ( my $row = $parser->fetch ) {
    say join("\t", @$row);
}

die $parser->errstr if $parser->errstr;
```

#### Output:

```
1234    text1,text2
5678    text3
90      text4,text5
```

Note that performance will be poor because `Parse::CSV` is splitting the columns for you, but then you immediately join them back together again.

---

However, since it appears that you're not working with a true CSV (columns containing the delimiter aren't quoted or escaped in any way), why not just use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) with a third argument to specify the maximum number of fields?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.csv' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;

    my @fields = split(',', $_, 2);
    say join("\t", @fields);
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Well my CSV files are 3-10Gb large. I am looking for an efficient way to parse them

Comment: @Bijan `split` is efficient, especially in the 3-argument form I've shown above. Did you run a benchmark that makes you think otherwise?

Comment: No benchmark has been run. With my current method (See [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90441/parsing-large-csv-in-perl)) I am running out of memory even though I have 32Gb so I am looking for a more efficient method.

Comment: @Bijan Ah, so this was an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your memory issue has more to do with the fact that you're keeping multiple copies of large XML documents in memory at a time than with how you parse the CSV. You have one copied stored in `$line`, one copy in `$report`, and one copy in `$xp`. Next time, post the real issue you're having; you'll get better help that way.